# Moving average filter implementation in the floating point

Tags: digital-filters, c++, moving-average, floating-point

I have following C++ implementation of the moving average digital filter.

```
template<uint32_t WINDOW_SIZE>
class MovingAverage{
    public:
        MovingAverage(){
            for(uint32_t elem = 0; elem < WINDOW_SIZE; elem++){
                buffer[elem] = 0;
            }
            input_value = 0;
            sum = 0;
            average = 0;
            index = 0;
        }
        
        void setInput(float input){
            input_value = input;
        }
        
        void calculate(){
            sum -= buffer[index];
            buffer[index] = input_value;
            sum += buffer[index];
            average = sum/WINDOW_SIZE;
            index = (index + 1) % WINDOW_SIZE;
        }
        
        float getOutput(){
            return average;
        }
        
    private:
        float buffer[WINDOW_SIZE];
        float input_value;
        float sum;
        float average;
        uint32_t index;
};
```

I have encountered a weird behavior on the ARM Cortex A9 platform. In case I at first pass the values coming from the adc (those values fluctuates about 514) into the moving average with window size equal to 32 samples and then I force the value 128 to the filter then the filter outputs value about 126 instead of 128. At this moment the `buffer` contains value 128 in all its items but the `sum` contains different value than the expected `32*128`.
In case I run the filter algorithm on my PC it works as expected. Does anybody have any idea what could be the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Could be an initialization problem in your test rig. Once `sum` is wrong, it will stay wrong forever since you always add and subtract the same value.  If it runs fine on a PC the problem is probably not in the code you posted, but in the test harness around it

Comment: Without test code to replicate the problem, I can't see how much help we can be. And even with that test code, I suspect StackOverflow is a better place for this question. Feel free to request reopening if you think otherwise. But please give some rationale.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 514 is close enough to a power of two, when a floating point number crosses a power of two it looses one digit accuracy.

The floating point number will be stored with 24-bit mantissa.

Your sum will be around $2^{15}$, when the `sum` is less than $2^{15}$, your input will be accumulated with precision $2^{14-24}=2^{-10}$, if the `sum` accumulator is greater or equal $2^{15}$, then the exponent changes from $14$  to $15$ and the the bit $2^{-10}$ is rounded of, doing this systematically for a few thousands of iterations will accumulate to the error you are observing.

Let $E=2^{-11}$, and $-1/2 \le {\tt rand()} < 1/2$ a uniform random number, and `avg.step` set the input and calculate, and return the difference of the accumulated `sum` and the direct sum of the values in the `buffer`. Repeat the following.

```
    delta = E if s < 512 else -E
    s = avg.step(512 + delta)
    s = avg.step(512 + (-0.5 <= rand() <0.5))
```

The accumulated errors evolves like this

[image: s-evolution]

You should not see the same behavior if you are not crossing a power of two boundary. You could sacrifice a few bits precision to avoid this accumulated errors.

A quick solution is initialize your sum to a different value, then you subtract that value when you calculate the average. For signed inputs `sum = 3 * WINDOW_SIZE * MAX_INPUT`, then for inputs between `-MAX_INPUT` and `MAX_INPUT` the sum will stay in a range of numbers represented with the same exponent. For unsigned `MAX_INPUT * WINDOW_SIZE` gives you one additional bit accuracy. This is effectively making your computations fixed point.